# How to redirect to AngularJS app after login using ASP.Net Identity in MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project where it involves the feature of Login/Authentication using ASP.Net Identity. I used SQL Server database successfully and used Role based authentication. However, after successful login, I want to redirect the user to AngularJS app's page. 
For this, I have `app` folder in my project which consists app.js and other controller files to route.
I don't know how should I redirect to AngularJS app after users logins.

Any tips/comments would be really helpful.

Comment: you need to server the html page from your app, usually the root page of `angular` is **index.html** but you look for a page that has `ng-app` or something in it. once found just redirect to "**/path/to/your.html**"

Comment: It's `Index.cshtml` page which contains the `ng-app`. In this `Index.cshtml`file, I am rendering AngularJS content and other views.  This is not working.. :(

Comment: have your included `angular.js` file

Comment: Yes it is in `/Scripts`folder of my project

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you need to make sure that your file containing ng-app is part of a proper route.  You need your view set up (/Home/Index.cshtml) then you need a HomeController with a method called Index that returns a view.